# Unable to insert an image in a dialog modal of Material Design Lite

Tags: html, image, css, material-design-lite

As shown in the codepen, the class `.mdl-dialog__content` won't work as a container and get adjusted per image's size. Have no clue how to get this working. Thank you.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XKGrPz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give the modal that image as background

```
.mdl-dialog {
  background: url('https://static.squarespace.com/static/52536652e4b007332ef4ecf4/52dec946e4b0ca499f87bce7/52dec978e4b0ca499f88ed14/1327377105003/1000w/CIPCreative_WHATEVER60.jpg');
}
```

Or if you want to keep that image in your html give the image `width:100%;`

Comment: Had already tried that. A buddy from gitter recommended to set the image's width and height as 100% and it did the trick. Thanks though.

Comment: @Hyperion I had write that for the width in my edited answer :)